# Is there a standalone install for the VS Code CLI, for use on e.g. build servers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I'm trying to automate build and deployment of dacpacs built in VS Code. Intending to use logic similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/devops/dotnet-cli-and-continuous-integration?tabs=powershell#manual-setup) in the CICD pipeline to get the pipeline. Building a sqlproj requires a build directory with the system dacpacs and targets file, which is found in the [SQL DB extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-database-project-extension-build-from-command-line?view=sql-server-ver16#build-the-project-from-the-command-line). If we're updating the build server CLI tools version every time, we should also be updating the build directory (i.e. the SQL DB extension), which we can do from the [command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions).

I can only find installation instructions that require a full VS Code install - I would like to avoid this for the build server. Is there a standalone install for the CLI independent of the UI, or should I go some other route like source controlling the build directory?

Comment: I'm confused. What does it mean to use [the VS Code CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions) without a VS Code installation? Why would you want that? I don't really understand the background (sorry). Can you try to elaborate or explain some more?

Comment: @starball it's quite common for providers to offer a lightweight CLI for build servers that avoids taking up unnecessary space with all the UI stuff that a CICD pipeline won't use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *CLI* is available from the [alternate downloads](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) section.

```
code tunnel
```

Additional resources available from [vscode docs/remote/tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) and the [remote - tunnels](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.remote-server) extension pages.

Comment: Thanks! I swear I couldn't see the additional downloads when I was on that page, but I also think I must have landed on a different download page...

Unfortunately it seems that it isn't possible to run the CLI without a full VS install on the machine, so definitively rules this out as an option (from the command line):

code.exe --install-extension ms-mssql.sql-database-projects-vscode
No installation of Visual Studio Code Stable was found.
Install it from https://code.visualstudio.com and try again.

Comment: Right, you don't use the CLI to install the extension. You first setup the tunnel, then you connect to the tunnel, and then you install the extension. It is the "vscode server" process that will handle installing the extension on the remote machine.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the CLI was a standalone install. I suppose this isn't really suitable for a CICD situation since we won't be triggering build actions via a client as it seems tunnels are designed for.